# Runner eclipse plugin doesn't show uncategorized folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, runner

When I go to the runner tab in eclipse, I can not find the uncategorized folder. It does not appear!

There is no relevant information in the eclipse's marketplace
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner

I am using eclipse neon, in the folder: eclipse_neon\eclipse\plugins I didn't find a folder related to the runner plugin.

I have been creating new Run o Debug configurations. However, I can not access them, probably due to they are in the uncategorized folder.

I removed the plugin and then I installed it, but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

In the workspace >.metadata >.plugins >com.eclipserunner.plugin, there is a .xml file. I opened this file using Sublime Text and I changed the name of the "Uncategorized" category, then I restart eclipse and the folder appeared.